# Inaccurate date function in javascript under node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, variables

I have this JS:

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDay();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
var seconds = d.getSeconds();
var milliseconds = d.getMilliseconds();
var timeStamp = year + '.' + month + '.' + day + '. ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ':' + milliseconds;
```

What it's outputting:

`2015.10.5. 11:45:22:307`

But what it should be outputting:

`2015.11.5. 11:45:22:307`

What is the problem with my script? Why the month is not correct?

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 2):

because getMonth method return the month from 0 to 11

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp